# Attaching an image to an animated plane

Tags: animation, image, parent

[image]

I have an animated page (plane) which uses NLA to move.

I am not having any luck *attaching* an imported image (image plane) onto the same plane so that it inherits all of the same modifiers and animation.

I've tried parenting the image to the page but that doesn't work.

My blend file is [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6603/).

Comment: what is your final goal? If you want the picture to appear on the surface, why don't you use it as an Image Texture in the Shader Editor?

Comment: @moonboots the goal is to attach multiple pics to the animated plane (i.e. 1-4 images attached to the page via script).  The hope was to animated the page once and then just parent the other images onto it.

Comment: When you say attach the other images do you mean in a magazine layout on a single page or multiple pages? The download link reports 404, you can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @rob: thx, upd the link.  I'd like to have an animated page of 1-4 images (i.e. a photobook layout) where  the images adhere to the animation of the parent page.  The plan is to import and parent the images via script so that it can be used on a directory of images - not preset to specific images.

Comment: So you should be able to subdivide your image plane and then add a Curve Modifier targeting your page. But I tried that with your .blend and could not get it to work except for when the image plane is on the left. I think it is because certain things have not had transforms applied.

Comment: Got it working by taking a different approach to the animation/deformation.  Used a lattice to deform the page and added that modifier to the image... and that's working.  Thanks for your help.